# It doesn't work when i click on a button in MainActivity in order to show other activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Please I'm trying to create an activity with 6 buttons, and 6 textviews. Note that the problem gone  when I click the button because it works when I tried to comment on block my code and just let this:

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 setContentView(R.layout.tasbih);
```

Her is my activity if you understand were the problem remains please help me:

```
public class Tasbih extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView textView, textView2, textView6;
private Button button7, button8, button9, button10, button11, button12;
private int j = 0;
private int k = 0;
private int l = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.tasbih);

 textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView6=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    button7=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);
    button8=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
    button9=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button9);
    button10=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button10);
    button11=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button11);
    button12=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button12);
    button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            j++;
            textView.setText(j);
        }
    }) ;
    button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                       j=0;
                                       textView.setText(j);
                                   }
                               });
            button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    k++;
                    textView2.setText(k);
                }
            });
    button10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            k=0;
            textView2.setText(k);
        }
    }) ;
    button11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            l++;
            textView6.setText(l);
        }
    }) ;
    button12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            l=0;
            textView6.setText(l);
        }
    }) ;

    final SharedPreferences sp= 
  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    j = sp.getInt("j", 0);
    k = sp.getInt("k", 0);
    l = sp.getInt("l", 0);
    textView.setText(j);
    textView2.setText(k);
    textView6.setText(l);

    textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, 
          int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int 
            count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putInt("j", j).apply();
        }
    });



    textView2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, 
   int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putInt("k", k).apply();
        }
    });



    textView6.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putInt("l", l).apply();
        }
    });
     }

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

   /* SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("tasbih1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putInt("j", j);
    editor.putInt("k", k);
    editor.putInt("l", l);
    editor.commit();*/

}

 }
```

Where is the problem ?!

Comment: Do you want to change activity on a button click? Sorry your question is kind of confusing me

Comment: When my activity contains only this code ( super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 setContentView(R.layout.tasbih); ). in onCreate () the button works and show me the activity Tasbih.class but when I add other sentences ( see the long code) it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please have a look on how to provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and than try to provide a MWE by editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can open other activity from current activity by intent. Like this.

You can add this line in your button click listner. Replace OtherActivity.class name to the class name of your other activity.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Tasbih.this,OtherActivity.class));
```